# Regex condition for extra white spaces between words in a string

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-group

```
^(?=\S)^[ `\'\.\-&A-Za-z0-9u00C0-u017F]+(?<=\S)$
```

Is what I've come up with but I don't know how to check for white spaces extra white spaces between words in the middle of the string

Comment: Please add some positive and negative examples of allowed/disallowed strings and add a programming language (if any).

Comment: [ `\'\.\-&A-Za-z0-9u00C0-u017F]+ this is a regex for allowed strings. the one before and the one after that are the regex that check for white spaces.
I need to add extra check for 2 or more white spaces between words in the middle of the string. Language is Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you don't want: leading or trailing white spaces or extra white spaces between words.
Then you want a string composed of single white space delimited words.

I'll proceed with `^\S+(?:\s\S+)*$`.

In details:

```
^      # Matches at the beginning of the string
\S+    # Matches one or more non-spacing character
(?:    # Starts a non-capturing group
  \s   # Matches one spacing character
  \S+  # Matches one or more non-spacing character
)*     # Repeat non-capturing group zero or more times
$      # Matches at the end of string
```

Testing [here](https://regex101.com/r/gGUMTG/1/)

Comment: Thanks, this looks more respectably than what I've come up with: `^(?=\S)^[ ``\'\.\,\-/&A-Za-z0-9À-ſ]+(?<=\S)(?<!\s{2,}.+)$`But I still have this symbol-allow condition `^[ ``\'\.\,\-/&A-Za-z0-9À-ſ]+ ` That needs to be kept. How would your suggestion look if it was merged with that condition? Many thanks already

Comment: I'd then simply replace `\S` in the proposed regex by `[\`\'\.\-&A-Za-z0-9u00C0-u017F]`, giving `^[\`\'\.\-&A-Za-z0-9u00C0-u017F]+(?:\s[\`\'\.\-&A-Za-z0-9u00C0-u017F]+)*$`.